# Installing my script in localhost and get error

Tags: localhost

I have a script that installed on web host but when I want to install and run it on localhost get this error:

```
setLogPath($config['debugger_log_dir']);
 $debugger->setDebuggerTemplates($config['debugger_template_dir']);
 //Start debugger timer $debugger->measureRunTime();
 // Initialize db object for the queries $db = new Database($db_config);
 //Start settings autocreater $SettingsParser = new SettingsParser(ROOT_PATH . "core/3WFW/Settings.php",&$config);
 $settings = $SettingsParser->load();
 /* if($settings['setting_site_status'] == 'offline'){ $ips = $db->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM `allow_ips`");
 $rIps = array();
 foreach($ips AS $k=>$v){ $rIps[] = $v['ip'];
 } if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $rIps)){ echo $settings['setting_offline_message'];
 exit();
 } } */ //set timezone ini_set('date.timezone', $settings['setting_server_timezone']);
 //set cookies session_set_cookie_params($settings['setting_cookie_lifetime']);
 session_regenerate_id();
 //    Start the template system $smarty = new Smarty();
 //$smarty->template_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'application/templates/'. $settings['setting_site_skin'] . '/';
 $smarty->compile_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache_template/';
 $smarty->config_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache_template/';
 $smarty->cache_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache/';
 $smarty->debugging = false;
 $smarty->caching = $settings['setting_smarty_cache_status'];
 $smarty->compile_check = true;
 $smarty->cache_lifetime = $settings['setting_smarty_cache_lifetime'];
 // Start the cache system Loader::loadClass("Cache");
 // Find Out what the user is using Loader::loadClass("Browser");
 $settings['browser'] = Browser::detect();
 // Start the registry Registry::set($db, "db");
 Registry::set($smarty, "smarty");
 Registry::set($debugger, "debugger");
 Registry::set($config, "config");
 Registry::set($settings, "settings");
 Registry::set(new Cache($cache), "cache");
 isset($_SESSION['admin_lang']) ? $admin_lang = $_SESSION['admin_lang'] : $admin_lang = $settings['setting_admin_lang'];
 Registry::set(Language::loadAdmin($admin_lang), "adminlang");
 isset($_SESSION['front_lang']) ? $front_lang = $_SESSION['front_lang'] : $front_lang = $settings['setting_front_lang'];
 Language::initFront($front_lang);
 //    Registry::set(Language::loadFront($front_lang), "frontlang");
 Registry::set(Language::loadFront(), "frontlang");
 //Load SEO Router "OPTIONAL!" Loader::loadClass("Router");
 //Load CMS pages $cms = array('about','careers','faq','payment-methods','terms','privacy- policy','join',' checkoutsucc','checkoutfail','about-us');
 $cms_all = $db->fetchAll("SELECT url FROM cms_page WHERE menu IN ('aboutus', 'aboutyou', 'aboutbusiness','no-menu')");
 foreach($cms_all as $v){ if(!in_array($v['url'], $cms)) $cms[] = $v['url'];
 } $cms = implode('|', $cms);
 $seo_rules['cms']['pattern'] = "/\/({$cms})/i";
 //Start controller system $controller = new Controller();
 $controller->start(Router::checkURL($seo_rules));
 //    end time for script $debugger->measureRunTime();
 // Show //debugger if(false){ if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $config['developers_ips']) AND empty($_POST)){ $db->showSQLDebugger();
 $debugger->show_debugger();
 } } ?>
```

I edit db username and password correctly and I install that on web host but in local cant run it. can you help me?

Comment: That's not an error message, it's php code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Smarty and a handful of other libraries. If the code is not executing locally, you may need to check the permissions on the cache folders.

```
$smarty->template_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'application/templates/'. $settings['setting_site_skin'] . '/';
$smarty->compile_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache_template/';
$smarty->config_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache_template/';
$smarty->cache_dir = ROOT_PATH . 'temp/cache/';
```

Can you edit the original question to include the error message rather than the code you used to trigger the error? It might be complaining about not being able to write to the cache directories to compile the templates.

Comment: Also, do you have smarty and everything installed on localhost as well?

Comment: all these directories are writable by windows. I don't know smarty installed in my localhost. how can check it?

Comment: @user2779537: Try the sample php code [listed here](http://www.smarty.net/quick_install). Or follow the installation instructions there